# Undefined is not an function data[index].push

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, indexing, undefined

I have an array called:

```
const data = []
```

I made a function where I loop true the array to check if the name already exists.

```
 let index = data.findIndex(x => x.name == csh.val().color);
                console.log(index); <-- gives me the right index back
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data[index].population); <-- this gives me the right value back
                if (index === -1) {
                    data.push({
                        name: csh.val().color,
                        population: csh.val().color ? 1 : 1,
                        color: csh.val().color.toLowerCase(),
                        legendFontColor: '#7F7F7F',
                        legendFontSize: 15
                    });
                }else {
                    if(data && data[index]) {
                        data[index].push({
                            name: csh.val().color,
                            population: data[index].population + 1,
                            color: csh.val().color.toLowerCase(),
                            legendFontColor: '#7F7F7F',
                            legendFontSize: 15
                        })
                    }
                }
```

But I get an error in the else statement called: undefined is not an function on this line:

```
data[index].push({
```

UPDATE:

This is how the array looks like:

```
    const data = [
    { name: "brown", population: 5, color: 'brown', legendFontColor: '#7F7F7F', legendFontSize: 15 },
{ name: "red", population: 5, color: 'brown', legendFontColor: '#7F7F7F', legendFontSize: 15 },
]
```

Comment: object, not array?

Comment: I have an array with objects. I will update it so you can see how it looks.

Comment: by `data[index].push()` you're trying to push into object - use `data.push()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let index = data.findIndex(x => x.name == csh.val().color);
                console.log(index); <-- gives me the right index back
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data[index].population); <-- this gives me the right value back
                if (index === -1) {
                    data.push({
                        name: csh.val().color,
                        population: csh.val().color ? 1 : 1,
                        color: csh.val().color.toLowerCase(),
                        legendFontColor: '#7F7F7F',
                        legendFontSize: 15
                    });
                }else {
                       data[index] = {
                            name: csh.val().color,
                            population: data[index].population + 1,
                            color: csh.val().color.toLowerCase(),
                            legendFontColor: '#7F7F7F',
                            legendFontSize: 15
                        }
                }
```